# If I had a Math.Max object, how would I get it to display a name rather than a number?

Tags: javascript

Say I have the following code in

```
var x = 4
var y = 6

function myFunction() {
    document.write(Math.max(x, y));
}
```

If I had a button pressed to give me the results of the Math object, how would I get it to display y for 6 instead of the number itself?

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: `Math.max` does not return a "Math.max object." It returns a number. There's no such thing as a "Math object."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you still want to use `Math.max`:

```
function myFunction() {
    if (Math.max(x, y) === x)
        document.write('x');
    else
        document.write('y');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if(x>y)
    document.write("x");
else
    document.write("y");
```

Is that what you are asking?

Comment: I know of that method, however I am looking for a method that involves using the math object.

Comment: @JohnsonGale Why? If you have specific requirements of the answer you should state them in the question.

Comment: I thought it was obvious considering I mentioned the Math object in both the Title and details of the question along with the code itself.

Answer (score 2):

You would associate the name with the value, for example:

```
var values = [
  { name: 'x', value: 4 },
  { name: 'y', value: 6 },
  { name: 'z', value: 5 }
];

function myFunction() {
  // sort the values to get the largest first
  values.sort(function(a, b){ return b.value - a.value });
  // display the name of the largest value
  document.write(values[0].name);
}
```